# detecting which page load when using turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I understand that I can trigger JavsScript on every page load when using turbolinks by using:

```
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

..but what's the best way to only trigger a JS block when a particular page (e.g. home page, so don't run JS for other pages) is loaded? I'm thinking to just wrap the content within a wrapper class like so for a page I have a specific piece of JS for:

```
<div class="homeWrapper">
...homepage...
</div>
```

..then do something like:

```
$(".homeWrapper .whatever") or $(".homeWrapper").find(".whatever")
```

.. but I'm worried if I have to do this for every pages elements on every page load it might slow the page down (too many jqueries). Is there a better way to do this, or is this the most common approach for Turbolink pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [`.length()`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) function in JQuery to do this:

```
var el = $(".element");

if ( el.length > 0 ) {
    //do something here
}
```